# Two definitions of homotopy, continuity.

Tags: general-topology

[Wikipedia definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Formal_definition)

With what topology is $t\rightarrow f_t$ continuous?  Some function topology?

Comment: If you're referring to the maps $t\rightarrow h_t(x)$ , then these are maps from $[0,1]$ into Y, and I assume [0,1] has the subspace topology of $\mathbb R$, so these are continuous as maps from [0,1] to Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the "compact-open topology" on the space of continuous functions from the interval to your space